Why do older TV anime use non-animated shots?
Although I don't watch 60's and 70s TV anime that often, but some anime that I saw had shots that weren't animated, there are shots that's a single cel without camera movement or a single cel with the camera zooming or panning within the shot, or illustrations like a painting or drawing in certain scenes, why do older anime do that? What's the reason behind it? I know the art of old TV anime is based on manga, but why do they do it?

A lot of newer anime still do this.

Of course 80s and 90s anime do that too, like the Black Jack anime that uses still illustrations within certain scenes.

Anime still do that because it is cheaper and faster to make

A one-minute explanation from Invincible S02E07 that is worth more than a million words. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uhndpv7sEqE

That clip is the animation of anime in a nutshell. That explains a lot.
